# Не работает код телеграмм бота на питоне

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
TOKEN = 

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start (message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
    item1 = typesKeyBoardButton('Товар')
    item2 = typesKeyBoardButton('Наличие товара')
    item3 = typesKeyBoardButton('Профиль')
    item4 = typesKeyBoardButton('​​О нас​')
    item5 = typesKeyBoardButton('Правила')
    item6 = typesKeyBoardButton('Поддержка')
    
    markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6)
    
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет дорогой {0.first_name}! \nТы находишься в боте для анонимной покупки товаров\n Мы заботимся о вас.❤️‍'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup = markup)
    
bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

буду благодарен если поможете

Answer (score 0):

Есть много причин почему бот может не работать - одна из них вы не обновили библиотеку pytelegramapi. Сделайте это через команды в консоли (Windows, но суть одна и та же): `pip uninstall telebot`, `pip install pytelegrambotapi` и `pip install pytelegrambotapi -U`.

Возможно стоит загуглить ошибки, которые сыпятся.

И, вы лучше токен то свой никому не показывайте а то вот так вот на весь Stackoverflow рассказали как к вам к боту попасть...